# Thymeleaf Spring adding dynamic content without replacing static content

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a web template and I want to reuse that HTML code for putting as a template on all the pages. On my destination page, I have some static HTML code

```
<div id="someID">
 <table id="test"></table>
</div>
```

I want to replace this div someID with a wrapper div using th:include tag but that will replace all the content of the someID div which I don't want. I just want to inject new code without replacing static data
My template page

```
<div id="wrapper" th:fragment="wrapper" >
```

Comment: I want to include wrapper div in someID div but if i use th:include it will replace table with contents of wrapper . But i want to keep table as it is

Comment: Why don't you add your table to your fragment instead?

Comment: That table is just one of the content for a given page .I have different contents for different page but the html template which i mentioned it in wrapper remains same for different pages too

Comment: Just a wild guess: are you trying to create a template that can be filled with different content? If so take a look at the layout dialect.

Comment: Ya trying to do that thing but cant it be done without any extension ie plain thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="control-group" th:fragment="buttons (frag)">
    <div class="controls" th:include="this :: ${frag}"></div>
</div>


        <div th:include="/templates/controls.html :: buttons('buttons')">
            <div th:fragment="buttons">
                <input type="submit" id="proceed" name="_eventId_proceed"
                    th:value="#{proceed}" value="Proceed!" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="submit" id="cancel" name="_eventId_cancel"
                    th:value="#{cancel}" value="Cancel!" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>  
        </div>
```